# Is it possible to use the same class in different OCL packages?

Tags: abstraction, ocl

I would like to use OCL to link two class diagrams that represent the same model at two levels of abstraction.

To illustrate, consider an abstract model A that contains a class Person that has a 'parents' association to itself. And a more concrete model B, that has classes Person, Male and Female, with Male and Female inheriting from Person, and two associations, one 'father' between Person and Male, and one 'mother' between Person and Female.

I would like to use OCL to link the two models together. That is, I would like to say that 'mother' and 'father' in the concrete model represent the 'parents' association in the abstract model.

I know it is possible to put all the associations in a single model and then to say something like

```
context Person inv:
 self.mother->forAll(m | m in self.parents) and
 self.father->forAll(f | f in self.parents) and
 self.parents->forAll(p | p in self.mother or p in self.mother)
```

But I specifically want to separate the models. The idea is that the concrete model does not have to carry the abstractions explicitly with it.

I have thought of using packages to place each model in a separate namespace, but then as far as I can understand, I end up with two different Person classes, one in each package.

Is there a way that I can say that two class names in the different packages represent the same class? that is the same set of objects? for example, would the following expression achieve this or would it simply be always false?

```
Abstract::Person.allInstances() = Concrete::Person.allInstances()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have thought of using packages to place each model in a separate namespace, but then as far as I can understand, I end up with two different Person classes, one in each package.

Right. Unless you define a package merge from the `Abstract` package to the `Concrete` package.

Package Merge is defined in section 12.2.3 of UML:

> *This capability is designed to be used when elements defined in
>   different Packages have the same name and are intended to represent
>   the same concept (...)  Thus, any reference to a model element
>   contained in the receiving Package implies a reference to the results
>   of the merge rather than to the increment that is contained in that
>   Package.* [UML 2.5]

```
package Abstract
context Person 
inv: not self->closure(parent)->contains(self)

package Concrete -- merges from package Abstract
context Person
inv: parents->asSet() = Set {mother, father}
```

But if you merge package `Abstract` into package `Concrete`, then `Concrete::Person` will bring `parents` from `Abstract::Person`, and you don't want that.

> I specifically want to separate the models. The idea is that the concrete model does not have to carry the abstractions explicitly with it.

Note that an instace is not restricted to a single supertype, then you can specify that every `Concrete::Person` is an `Abstract::Person`, and every `Abstract::Person` is a `Concrete::Person`

```
package Abstract 
context Person inv: self->oclIsKindOf(Concrete::Person)

package Concrete
context Person 
inv: self->oclIsKindOf(Abstract::Person) 
inv: self->oclAsType(Abstract::Person).parents->asSet() = Set {mother, father}
```

The cast is required because `Concrete::Person` does not know about the associations in `Abstract::Person` (they are different types, even when both apply to the same instances).

Also, the first invariant on `Concrete::Person` is actually redundant, because `oclAsType` will return `invalid` if self does not conform `Abstract::Person`.

Comment: Hi Javier, thanks for the detailed answer. I think that your `merge` approach comes closest to what I want, but I don't think that the`oclIsKindOf` approach will work because according to the OCL 2.4 standard: 

_The `oclIsKindOf` property determines whether `t` is either the direct type or one of the supertypes of an object._

In other words it is a predicate, so using it in the invariant will simply make the invariant false.

Comment: if `Concrete::Person` is not *the direct type or one of the supertypes of* an instance of `Abstract::Person`, then the invariant is false... but we already said that **every** instance of `Abstract::Person` is also a `Concrete::Person` (because it is the same concept), then the invariant is always true; and it is there in order to require that the model is consistent.

Comment: But how did we say that every instance of `Abstract::Person` is also a `Concrete::Person`? was that said with an OCL expression? or did we just say that outside the formal framework?

Comment: `self->oclIsKindOf(Concrete::Person)` is an invariant of `Abstract::Person`

Comment: So whatever I write in an invariant becomes true?

Comment: I think that this is not the intention of the OCL standard. In section 12.6 the definition of Invariant is: 

An invariant constraint is a constraint that is linked to a Classifier... The expression must be true for each instance of the classifier at any moment in time. Only when an instance is executing an operation, this
does not need to evaluate to true.

So, the invariant  is a predicate that _must_ evaluate to true and not a fact that becomes true merely by stating it in the invariant. 

Do you think I got this wrong?

Comment: That may be an interesting question on its own, but in short yes, invariants become true, because they *must* be true.
See the examples in 7.3.3: `self.numberOfEmployees > 50`. What would happen if a company has 20 employees? Of course a collection may contain 20 elements, but that instance violates the constraint.

Comment: Hmm, so in that case what if I write in an invariant 1 = 2?

Comment: In that case your model will be inconsistent.

Comment: Exactly. But why is it consistent in the previous case? how can OCL know the difference between `oclIsKindOf` and `1=2`?

Answer (score 0):

(RSS suggests that this is a new topic!)

The problem is that you abstract/concrete variants are in some sense different classes, but in another sense the same classes. You must therefore partition your consumers according to whether they want to see abstract/concrete as different/same classes and define what 'same' means for each consumer.

For humans, you can use spelling conventions to make different classes the 'same'. Or annotations or the myriad UML associations.

If you want some degree of functional sameness allowing an 'abstract'/'concrete' class to be used interchangeably in some simulation you perhaps need both 'abstract' and concrete classes to inherit from a shared interface for which you have distinct 'abstract'/'concrete' implementations.

If the sameness is for documentation purposes, you might consider a model transformation language that converts one to the other. Many M2Ms are really just an outer language for OCL providing support for model import/export and mutation. The M2M could capture regular idioms that relate 'abstract' and 'concrete' and might be amenable to mathematical proof and/or automated code generation. It should certainly satisfy requirements tracing necessities.